# What is best way to run periodic consumer for redis or kafka in Ktor backend?

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, schedule, ktor, consumer

I'm trying to use Ktor for my new backend, and I have a question about how can I launch periodic consumer for kafka or redis inside Ktor backend application.

In very simple way, I thought that I make a single backend application configurable to enable routing and consuming, thus some of instance will support both, and some of instance will support only routing to ensure availability.

But, I'm not sure how can I trigger consumer application from ktor. From the code I tested with this,

```kotlin
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "127.0.0.1") {
        configureDependencyInjection()
        configureRouting()
        configureSecurity()
        configureSerialization()
        configureExceptionHandling()
        configureMonitoring()
        consumerStarting() // this is consumer starting.
    }.start(wait = true)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
fun Application.consumerStarting() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        // todo: make this in to rule activator initializer
        println("TEST")
        delay(3.seconds)
        consumerStarting()
    }
}
```

And, when I tested this, I can see that "TEST" will be printed every 3 seconds.
Similar to this way, I thought that I can start monitoring instances from `Application.consumerStarting()` (e.g. periodically fetch stream from redis, consume it we coroutine, etc.).

But I'm not sure it is right way because I cannot find any references for this situation with Ktor.

Any comment will be welcome.

Comment: What's the use case here? Kafka consumer ideally runs continously, not in batches

Comment: @OneCricketeer The use case is, some api's will store configuration for the event consuming, and consumer will consume kafka stream events, and produce some action (e.g. add other kafka stream events for coresponding events). But I'm not sure what is the best way to do that.